# How switch a 3v load high side, from a uC powered from same 3v?

Tags: transistors, switches

I have a uC (Arduino Mini) powered from 2xAA battery pack.
The Mini display some data on a circuit with a MAX7219 + 2x7segments 4 digits led (a total of 8 numbers).

Because it is powered from battery (and for learning) I want to switch off the load totally when Arduino sleeps, and power on only when needed.

So, this is the very basic schematic (U1 the uC and U3 the load)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyu1uP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know that for the high side switch I need a PNP, and with a PNP I need mantain GPIO HIGH (right?). But if Arduino sleeps, how it can mantain high?

But, other this question, I'm tryng to study transistors and FET/Mosfet from some months, but I find they very difficult to learn.

Please, can you help me with:

1) Know if circuit is right (R1 for limit base)

2) How can I select a transistor? What I need to check in datasheet?

3) I have some part available, are there some part available for my goal? (Mix of NPN, PNP, FET and Mosfet:

PNP:

- 2N3906

NPN:

- P2N2222A
- 2N3904

N CHANNEL MOSFET

- FQP30N06L
- 2N7000

P CHANNEL MOSFET

- NDP6020P

NPN POWER

- BD239C
- TIP120

N CHANNEL JFET

- PN4391

DARLINGTON

- ULN2003A

Thank you

Comment: A couple of tips on schematic drawing: (1) With the CircuitLab tool you can save the editable schematic in your post. You don't need to take a screengrab. That way we can copy it into our answers and edit it. (2) Draw components with + at top. Your battery supply is upside down. (3) If you double-click on the Custom Component you can name the pins. (4) If the Arduino GPIO goes into tri-state (input mode) when going to sleep then you probably just need to add a pull-up resistor between Q1 base-emitter to keep it turned off.

Comment: Just put a pullup :D

Comment: @Transistor thank you for your CL hints... but... on free cannot save or share :( Ok, I did understand the necessity of pullup... but, for my others question? Can you help me?

Comment: When you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar it's free. I might post an answer later.

Comment: Added the Circuit Lab scheme. Thank you, w8 for your answers later :)

Comment: @Transistor sorry for the "UP", looking also for your answer... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of 2N7000 (or 2N3904) (as driver) with NDP6020P (as main switch) will work for you. [See this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/42030/117785).

However, you don't need to invent new wheels. The device you are looking for is called "high-side" switch. There are many of them. Here is a typical device for you, [SP2525A](https://www.exar.com/ds/sp2525a_ds_r210_110411.pdf):
[image]

The switch won't power your display until the EN is "high". So before enetering the Arduino sleep mode, turn the GPIO low. A pull-down resistor might help here.

Comment: Thank you. I will read with many attention the linked answer. At first glance, seems that I will find all my info for answer to 2, right? And the reason that you has told me use 2N7000 + NDP6020P, all right? THank you

Comment: I cannot figure how you did select that transistors, by the way. Thank you for your following explain :)

Comment: @sineverba, the idea of design/schematics is given the the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not an answer to your question, but have you considered using power-down mode of the LED driver? From MAX7219 datasheet: "the devices include a 150µA low-power shutdown mode". Simple software solution without any extra parts.

Comment: Yes, I could, but my goal is also learning transistors...